# SAP Ariba - API call via Postman

Tags: api, asynchronous, postman, sap-ariba

I am new to API world and having issue  data from SAP Ariba.  I've attached screen prints of my URL, header, body & Error message.

"AdvancePaymentFactSystemView" is built-in view that's available in our Ariba environment. Any help is appreciated.

API_URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmZyl.jpgBody https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6nz9.jpgHeader https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsoxO.jpg

I need to pull data in JSON format from the built-in view.